# Informatiion inside a tag

Tags: javascript, beautifulsoup

```
<td valign="top">
<script language="JavaScript">genUserFriendlyCourseStatus('W')</script>Request</td>
```

I want to get the text "Request". I did the following:

```
p = soup.findAll("script") 
p.nextSibling
```

But it gave me `null`. I tried `soup.text` also but then it just gave the information inside the script tag and did not give "Request" at all. Please advise.

Comment: <td valign="top"><script language="JavaScript">genUserFriendlyCourseStatus('W')</script>Request</td>   this is html code from which i need information request

Comment: Are you saying you want the code in the script element to somehow retrieve the text "Request" that immediately follows the script element?

Comment: I just want to get string request. I searched on internet and learnt about method of parse tree in which you do nextSibing.

Comment: But is there some other method also that can help me get string Request

Answer (score 0):

First of all, script tag is a single tag not a list of tags so dont use findall. Following should help -

```
import re
p = soup.find('script', text=re.compile('genUserFriendlyCourseStatus'))
print p.next_sibling.text
```